# How to click toggle switch in webdriverIO

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

the HTML Element looks like
`<div class="toggleButton" ng-class="{checked: settings.$storage.enabledApps[app.name]}" ng-click="settings.apps.toggleApp(app.name)"><input class="workplayEnabled switch" type="checkbox" ng-checked="settings.$storage.enabledApps[app.name]"></div>`

i tried `browser.click('.toggleButton .switch'),browser.click('.toggleButton'), browser.click(' .switch')`

but it's not working
it throws the error as element not visible
whereas if i try `browser.isSelected('.toggleButton .switch'),browser.isSelected('.toggleButton'), browser.isSelected(' .switch')` it returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, it's really hard to pin-point your **EXACT** problem as you're doing multiple things wrong.

**HTML breakdown:**

- that is HTML generated via AngularJS;
- if you analyze the Angular attributes (`ng`-attributes/directives) you'll notice only your `<div>` has click-triggered functionality added (via `ng-click="settings.apps.toggleApp(app.name)"`), thus you only have to target the `<div>` element;
- the `<input>` only has reactive behavior (if the toggle-button is checked, then it gets populated on `ng-checked` trigger);

**Your problem:** Now that we narrowed down the solution to clicking your `<div>`, we need to make sure your selector is returning the correct element.

- open your Angular app, open the browser console & try seeing if your selector is working (e.g.: `$(div.toggleButton)`). If the CSS-selector returns more than an element(`$(div.toggleButton).length > 1`), that means you have multiple `<div>`s with that class so you will have to find a more specific locator;
- after you have found the correct locator for your `<div>`, I would add a `.debug()`(more info **[here](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/debug.html)**) prior to your click in your WebdriverIO script so I could easily debug the scenario;
- once in debug-mode, I would try with the same selector that found my element in the browser console.

**!!! Note:** `.isSelected()` will always return `false` in your scenario as you mentioned you failed to click the toggle switch, which is satisfying the `ng-checked` condition. You can verify this by manually selecting your toggle switch in debug-mode and then performing the `.isSelected()` command on your `<input>`. Then it should return `true`.